# Kernel of an evaluation homomorphism $\mathbb{C}[X_1,\dots, X_n] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

> Let $R:=\mathbb{C}[X_1,\dots, X_n]$, $a=(a_1,\dots, a_n)\in \mathbb{C}^n$ and $\phi_a:R\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $\phi_a(f)=f(a)$. I want to show that $\ker(\phi_a)=(X_1-a_1,\dots, X_n -a_n)$.

I know that to be true for $n=1$ and I also know that $\ker(\phi_a)$  is a maximal ideal in $R$. Moreover, $(X_1-a_1,\dots, X_n -a_n) \subseteq \ker(\phi_a)$ is obvious.  I am note sure if I can do an induction in this case.  Thank you.

Comment: Induction shouldn't be necessary. Have you learned about any 'isomorphism theorems' yet?

Comment: Yes, this is how I know that $\ker(\Phi_a)$ is a maximal ideal.

Comment: I guess you could show that $(X_1-a_1,\ldots,X_n-a_n)$ is maximal in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Then, if one contains the other, what can be said?

Comment: @Alex Maximal in $\mathbb C[X_1,\dots,X_n]$.

Comment: Oops! Of course not in $\mathbb{C}^n$...

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, you can assume that $a=0 \in \mathbb C^n$.

Then you want to show that if $f(0,0,\cdots,0)=0$, then $f \in \langle X_1,\cdots, X_n \rangle= \mathfrak m$.

Write $f$ as a sum of monomials, and observe that the constant terms must vanish. This implies that $f \in \mathfrak m$.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Why isn't generality lost?

Comment: @Zolf69 Because you can always find an isomorphism $f:\mathbb C[X_1,\cdots,X_n] \to \mathbb C[X_1,\cdots,X_n]$ sending the origin to any other point. Just sends $X_i \mapsto X_i - a_i$.